# Rotate triangle of user in navigation map MAPBOX ANDROID

Tags: navigation, mapbox, heading, bearing

[I am make a app navigation by mapbox. Now I want to edit mapbox, I want to rotate triangle of user on navigation map when user rotate the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONr07.png)

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried? Show your code.

Comment: I shared a picture, and I want to rotate icon which i circle it

Comment: Do you use Skype? please give me your skype id, I will explain to you, thanks for helping